# How to add Request header in WordPress remote api calls

Tags: plugin-development, wp-remote-get, wp-remote-post

Hey am new to WP development, can any one tell me how to add request headers in wp_remote_get() or wp_remote_post() remote api calls.

I tried the following but didnt work

```
    $response = wp_remote_get( add_query_arg( array(
        'Affiliate-Id' => XXXXX,
        'Affiliate-Token'     => XXXXX
    ), $api_url ) , array( 'timeout' => 10));
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to send `Affiliate-Id` and `Affiliate-Token` in headers then you need to pass them in the optional arguments of `wp_remote_get` function.

Example:

```php
$response = wp_remote_get( $api_url , array( 
    'timeout' => 10,
    'headers' => array( 
        'Affiliate-Id' => XXXXX,
        'Affiliate-Token'=> XXXXX 
    ) 
));
```